# R - high dimension data using k means clustering

Tags: r, clustering, k-means, unsupervised-learning, high-dimensional

The dataset is 1000(observations) x 700(variables), After using pca to do dimension reduction, PC150 explained 85% Variance, so I use this (1000 x 150) data to do k means clustering.

This code was used to choose K:

```
wss <- (nrow(inputs)-1)*sum(apply(x,2,var))
for(i in 1:100) wss[i] <- sum(kmeans(x, centers=i)$withinss)
plot(1:100, wss, type="b", xlab="Number of Clusters", ylab="Within groups sum of squares")
```

[image]

I choose k = 80. The between_ss / total_ss is about 53% which is not good. Which k should I choose?

What should I do to improve the clustering? Are there any other methods to do a good clustering on this high-dimension data? I tried dbscan and hierarchical clustering(res = hclust(dist(x), method="complete" and "average"), the results seems no good either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no elbow in this plot.

This drop-off is the expected behavior from random data, and clearly **indicates that k-means completely failed on this data**.

I'd at least try without PCA, because you have much too few observations to do a stable PCA with so many dimensions. Recommendations range from n>3p to n>3p², much more if you have redundancies in your data or even binary attributes. Most likely, PCA also worked very poor.

Comment: Thank you! I tried k-means without PCA, the between_ss / total_ss is better.

Comment: Better than before, probably. But given only above plot I still doubt it is even remotely *good*.

Answer (score 3):

Reading through this, I was troubled by several things.

First, you don't ever say why you are doing this, what your data set is, why you have so many variables, what those variables are, why your N is so small relative to the number of variables and so on. We need context.

Second, your PCA should raise some warning flags. PCA is, in my experience, usually *much* more efficient. What data set could possibly need 150 dimensions to describe it? This gets back to the first point and adds - why these  variables?

Third, your cluster analysis didn't work at all. You tried several methods. The unfortunate conclusion (especially in light of the above) is that your data don't cluster. It seems, in fact, like you might have data that is either all noise or, at least, so noisy as to make analysis impossible.

So, I would suggest going back and figuring out not what is wrong with your methods, but what is wrong with your data and with the basic problem.

Comment: The data is from homework, it is a numeric matrix.